# Foreign key constraint raises error but it is deactivated

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys, sql-server-2014

***EDIT***: *My question has been incorrectly marked as duplicate. It is about the impossibility of truncating tables instead of just disabling constraints, which according to Larnu is not possible since I need to drop them.*

I have to empty a database and then shrink it. I have already run

`delete from` in all tables (`exec sp_MSforeachtable 'delete from ?'`).

The next step was to disable all constraints with

`alter table tableName nocheck constraint all` (`exec sp_MSforeachtable 'alter table ? nocheck constraint all'`)

and check they were indeed disabled:

```
select
     [Table]     = o2.name, 
     [Constraint] = o.name, 
     [Enabled]   = case when ((C.Status & 0x4000)) = 0 then 1 else 0 end
from sys.sysconstraints C
     inner join sys.sysobjects o on  o.id = c.constid and o.xtype='F'
     inner join sys.sysobjects o2 on o2.id = o.parent_obj
```

[image: check disabled constraints]

Even then, I still get the error:

```
Msg 4712, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Cannot truncate table '...' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Even if a key is disabled, you still can't `TRUNCATE` a table. The correct methodology would be `DROP FOREIGN KEY` -> `TRUNCATE TABLE` ->`CREATE FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: @IgorCova How is this question a duplicate? My question goes on the impossibility on truncating tables not to disable constraints (foreign keys), which according to Larnu is not possible since I need to drop them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to solve this, I did what @Larnu indicated in the comments section:

"The correct methodology would be DROP FOREIGN KEY -> TRUNCATE TABLE ->CREATE FOREIGN KEY".

So, 1st drop all constraints:

```
USE DATABASE;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER TABLE [DATABASE].' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) + 
    ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.foreign_keys;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

and 2nd truncate the tables:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'truncate table ?'
```

I didn't recreate the F. keys since the DB probably won't be used anymore.